# What is a $\langle , \rangle_{H}$? And how do you prove that it is an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

We were given this problem:

For the inner product space $V$ and its subspace $H$, let $Q = \{E(v)\,|\,v\in V\}$ be the vector space.

Define addition in $Q$ by: for $v, w\in V, E(v)\oplus E(w) = E(v + w)$.

Define scalar multiplication in Q by: for $v \in V$ and $\rho\in \mathbb{R}, \rho E(v) = E(\rho v)$.

For $v\in V$, define $E(v) = \{v+h\,|\,h\in H\}$.

Define for $u,v\in V$, and $u = u_1 + u_2, v = v_1 + v_2$ where $u_1, v_1 \in H$ and $u_2, v_2\in H^{\bot}$,
\begin{align*}
\langle E(u), E(v)\rangle_H = \langle u_2, v_2\rangle
\end{align*}

Prove or disprove: $\langle \, ,\,\rangle_H$ is an inner product on $Q$.

What is $\langle \,,\,\rangle_H$? Anyway, here are my initial thoughts in solving the problem:

To prove $\langle , \rangle_H$ is an inner product on $Q$, we have to prove the following:

1. For all $E(a), E(b), E(y)\in V$, $\langle E(a), E(b) + E(y)\rangle_H = \langle E(a), E(b)\rangle + \langle E(a), E(y)\rangle_H$.
   \begin{align*}
               \langle E(a), E(b) + E(y)\rangle_H = E(a)_H \cdot E(b + y)_H &= \begin{pmatrix}
               a_1\\
               a_2\\
               \vdots\\
               a_n
               \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
               b_1 + y_1\\
               b_2 + y_2\\
               \vdots\\
               b_n + y_n
               \end{pmatrix}\\
               &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i(b_i+y_i)\\
               &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iy_i\\
               &= \begin{pmatrix}
               a_1\\
               a_2\\
               \vdots\\
               a_n
               \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
               b_1\\
               b_2\\
               \vdots\\
               b_n
               \end{pmatrix} + 
               \begin{pmatrix}
               a_1\\
               a_2\\
               \vdots\\
               a_n
               \end{pmatrix} \cdot
               \begin{pmatrix}
               y_1\\
               y_2\\
               \vdots\\
               y_n
               \end{pmatrix}\\
               &= E(a)_H\cdot E(b)_H + E(a)_H \cdot E(y)_H\\
               &= \langle E(a), E(b)\rangle + \langle E(a), E(y)\rangle_H
           \end{align*}
2. For all vectors $a, b\in V$, $\langle a, b\rangle = \langle b, a\rangle$.
   \begin{align*}
               \langle a, b\rangle = E(a)_H\cdot E(b)_H &= \begin{pmatrix}
               a_1\\
               a_2\\
               \vdots\\
               a_n
               \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
               b_1\\
               b_2\\
               \vdots\\
               b_n
               \end{pmatrix}\\
               &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i\\
               &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_ia_i\\
               &= \begin{pmatrix}
               b_1\\
               b_2\\
               \vdots\\
               b_n
               \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
               a_1\\
               a_2\\
               \vdots\\
               a_n
               \end{pmatrix}\\
               &= E(b)_H\cdot E(a)_H\\
               &= \langle b, a\rangle
           \end{align*}
3. For all vectors $a, b$ and for all real numbers $r \in \mathbb{R}, \langle ra,b\rangle = r\langle a,b\rangle $.
   \begin{align*}
               \langle ra, b\rangle = E(ra)_H\cdot E(b)_H &= \begin{pmatrix}
               ra_1\\
               ra_2\\
               \vdots\\
               ra_n
               \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
               b_1\\
               b_2\\
               \vdots\\
               b_n
               \end{pmatrix}\\
               &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (ra_i)b_i\\
               &= r\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i\\
               &= r\begin{pmatrix}
               a_1\\
               a_2\\
               \vdots\\
               a_n
               \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
               b_1\\
               b_2\\
               \vdots\\
               b_n
               \end{pmatrix}\\
               &= r(E(a)_H\cdot E(b)_H)\\
               &= r\langle a,b\rangle
           \end{align*}
4. For all vectors $a\in V, \langle a,a \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle a,a \rangle = 0$ iff $a = 0$.
   \begin{align*}
               \langle a, a\rangle = E(a)_H \cdot E(a)_H &= \begin{pmatrix}
               a_1\\
               a_2\\
               \vdots\\
               a_n
               \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
               a_1\\
               a_2\\
               \vdots\\
               a_n
               \end{pmatrix}\\
               &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} {a_i}^2 \geq 0
           \end{align*}
   But then again, I have no idea what $\langle\,,\,\rangle_H$ is.

Comment: By "What is $\langle\ , \ \rangle_H$", do you mean "What $\langle\ , \ \rangle_H$ measures". Is it right?

Comment: More like what it really is. I'm not fond of the notations yet.

Comment: $\langle \,\,, \,\,\rangle_{H}$ has been defined by $\langle E(u), E(v)\rangle_{H}$ in the question.

Comment: It essentially defines an inner product on the quotient space $V/H$ using only the components of vectors in $H^\perp$.

Comment: So how do you treat it? It just looks so bizarre to me.

Comment: In each of 1. through 4., the vectors should be elements of $Q = V/H$, i.e., "cosets" or "affine translates" $E(v) = v + H$ of $H$. Each representative (element of $E(v)$) can be written _uniquely_ as $u_1+u_2$ in your notation, and a key point is that _every representative_ of $E(v)$ "has the same $u_2$". You can therefore express each of properties 1. through 4. as a condition about vectors in $V$....

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, $E(v)$ is a subset of $V$. Let us call such a set an $E$-set.

Next, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H$ is a function that takes two $E$-sets and returns a number; given $E(u)$ and $E(v)$ it returns $\langle u_2, v_2 \rangle,$ where $u_2,v_2$ are the $H^\bot$ components of $u,v$ respectively.

Then, if you can show that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H$ satisfies the criteria for being an inner product, then you have an inner product on the set of $E$-sets. You can then say things like "this $E$-set is orthogonal to this other $E$-set."

---

> To prove $\langle , \rangle_H$ is an inner product on $Q$, we have to prove the following:
>
> 1. For all vectors $a, b,$ and $y\in V$, $\langle a, (b + y)\rangle = \langle a,b\rangle + \langle a + y\rangle$.

Not for all $a,b,y\in V$ but for all $E$-sets $a,b,y,$ or
$$
\langle E(u), E(v)\oplus E(w) \rangle_H = \langle E(u), E(v) \rangle + \langle E(u), E(w) \rangle_H
$$
for $u,v,w\in V.$

*Proof*
$$
\langle E(u), E(v) \oplus E(w) \rangle_H
= \langle E(u), E(v+w) \rangle_H
= \langle u_2, (v+w)_2 \rangle
= \langle u_2, v_2+w_2 \rangle
\\
= \langle u_2, v_2 \rangle + \langle u_2, w_2 \rangle
= \langle E(u), E(v) \rangle_H + \langle E(u), E(w) \rangle_H.
$$
Note that you need to show first that $(v+w)_2=v_2+w_2.$ Everything else follows from definition of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H$ and from $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ being an inner product on $V.$

Comment: Given the OP’s inexperience, I think it would also help to add a brief explanation of why the inner product is even a function at all (for instance, it would not be a function if the RHS was $\langle u_1, v_1 \rangle$, and the OP may not be in a position to appreciate this subtlety).  It’s also not obvious whether they are familiar with addition and multiplication in $Q$ either, though that is really up to the OP to clarify.

Comment: Please check my proof for number 1 if it's correct.

Comment: I noticed that I missed one tiny detail in the problem. I forgot to include the definition of addition and scalar multiplication in $Q$:
Define addition in $Q$ by: for $v, w\in V, E(v)\oplus E(w) = E(v + w)$.

Define scalar multiplication in Q by: for $v \in V$ and $\rho\in \mathbb{R}, \rho E(v) = E(\rho v)$.

Comment: @muw. You rewrite things as column matrices. This means that you have decomposed $E(a)$ etc. in some basis. But doing this requires that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H$ is linear in each argument, which is what you want to show.

Comment: @muw. I added a proof of the first property (additivity in second position).

Comment: Checked your proof. So, basically my attempt is correct except for the part where I proved the first property?

Comment: @muw. No, you still need to know that things work with the basis vectors.